# Young Justice: How can Martian Manhunter have a niece?

Tags: dc, martian-manhunter, young-justice

How can it be possible that Martian Manhunter has a niece?

I'm talking about Young Justice. In the "Justice League" J'onn J'onnz was the unique Martian who survived. I couldn't find any explanation to explain this discrepancy.

Comment: 1. I edited the answer to clarify the wording. Hope you don't object to the edits, you can roll the back if needed. 2. You English is good enough to make it clear what you're asking about, so don't worry about it! Plenty of people here aren't native speakers (myself included), don't let your worries about your English discourage you - use it as opportunity to learn and improve it :)

Answer (score 6):

**In the previous DC Universe, The [Martian Manhunter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_Manhunter) did not have a niece. He was the last GREEN Martian. Miss Martian was a [White Martian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Martian) sent away in a rocket to a distant star system, Vega, during the last great war between the Green and White Martians. This war ultimately resulted in the near-destruction of the species. The Martian Manhunter and Miss Martian would have been mortal enemies. In the continuity of Young Justice, the Martian species is alive and well.**

### Earth #16 (Young Justice Earth)

On the Young Justice Earth ([**Earth #16**](http://youngjustice.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-16)), the Martian Manhunter does have a niece, the child of his sister and a White Martian. The Martian species, including [**Red, Green and White Martians**](http://youngjustice.wikia.com/wiki/Martian) are all very much alive, and are trying to establish diplomatic communication with Earth.

We are not privy to why the Martian Manhunter decides to lie to the Justice League. On Mars, White Martians are a servant underclass but that should not have meant much to the League, so he must have had other reasons. In the televised Young Justice, the League is displeased with J'onn but no other censure is made. Yet.

Under the tutelage of the Young Justice training program, Miss Martian's powers have continued to grow with practice. Her telepathic abilities and mental capacities are in some cases stronger or even eclipse The Martian Manhunter's.

Lately her use of her telepathic powers have had terrible consequences including trying to alter Conner Kent's (Superboy's) memory which lead to their breakup and her violent conflicts with the psychic [**Psimon**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psimon) and mind-controlling [**Queen Bee**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Bee_%28comics%29#Television) didn't help matters.

Her strength and ability to absorb information from the [**Krolotean**](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Kroloteans) minds, (leaving them gibbering, drooling, comatose idiots) has drawn questioning stares from many members of the Justice League and Young Justice. It is only the war time footing in the Invasion storyline that keeps this from being a greater issue. For now.

Answer (score 5):

In the comics, Miss Martian isn't actually related to the Martian Manhunter (but J'onn treats her as family), for she is a

> White Martian.

I'm not sure if her nature as a

> White Martian

has been revealed at the cartoon. TV shows often have a different canon than the comics, so this relation might be different.

Comment: Actually that was a major plot point in Season 2. But in terms of Young Justice cannon, they never really went into any depth regarding the history of Mars except mentioning your spoiler text and why that's a problem for Martians.

Answer (score -1):

Miss Martian (the YJ one) is not related to MM at all he is a Martian as well as she so why can't she be his family on a aboptable term? He is the last Green Martian and she is a White one. J’onn is taking in a young Martian as his own Niece ( he has a adopted daughter already) to show her the ways of Martianhood (idk if that’s a thing) I believe it doesn’t matter if she isn’t his actual niece or that she’s a different color than him. He took her under his wing and taught her well. Well enough that she will rival a few of his powers one day. There are many story lines on those two but the original arc is that she is of no relation. Another is where he lied about being the last green Martian alive.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence to back up these assertions?

Comment: His species is noted to be a human/ kryptonian hybrid and a meta human clone.